# Экземпляр класса в свойстве класса php

Tags: php, ооп

Только начал изучать ООП на php. 
Появилась необходимость создать класс для работы с файлами и архивами.
Собственно вопрос: как мне правильно создать экземпляр класса ZipArchive в моем классе, если он будет использоваться во многих методах моего класса?
В голову пришли варианты:

1) Не понятно как потом к нему обращаться

```
    class fileCreator {
        private $zipname;
        private $zip;
        public function __construct($zipname) {
             $this->zipname=$zipname;
             $this->zip= new ZipArchive();
        }
    }
```

2) Не работает, но возможно есть похожий вариант.

```
    class fileCreator {
        private $zipname;
        private $zip=new ZipArchive();
        public function __construct($zipname) {
             $this->zipname=$zipname;
        }
    }
```

3) Не создавать экземпляр ZipArchive в свойстве моего класса, а создавать его каждый раз в методе класса

```
    class fileCreator {
        private $zipname;
        public function __construct($zipname) {
             $this->zipname=$zipname;
        }
        public function func() {
             $zip=new ZipArchive();
        }
        public function func2() {
             $zip=new ZipArchive();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант корректен.

```
class fileCreator {
    private $zipname;
    private $zip;
    public function __construct($zipname) {
         $this->zipname=$zipname;
         $this->zip= new ZipArchive();
    }
}
```

> Непонятно как потом к нему обращаться

Из других методов? Точно так же, через `$this->zip`.

Comment: спасибо! так и сделаю

Answer (score 1):

```
class fileCreator {
    private $zipname;
    private $zip;
    public function __construct($zipname, ZipArchive $obj) {
         $this->zipname=$zipname;
         $this->zip= $obj;
    }
}

$zip=new ZipArchive();
$a=new fileCreator ($name,$zip);
```

способов много

Comment: спасибо, буду иметь в виду